# Why does this threading approach not work?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

I have a wierd problem with threading in an ASP.NET application. For some reason, when I run the code in the request thread, everything works as expected. But when I run it in a separate thread, nothing happens.
This is verified by calling the below handler with the three flags "on", "off" and "larma" respectively - in the two first cases everything works, but in the latter nothing happens.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

In the web project I have a generic handler with the following code:

```
If task = "on" Then
    Alarm.StartaLarm(personId)
    context.Response.Write("Larmet är PÅ")
ElseIf task = "off" Then
    Alarm.StoppaLarm(personId)
    context.Response.Write("Larmet är AV")
ElseIf task = "larma" Then
    Alarm.Larma(personId)
    context.Response.Write("Larmar... (stängs av automagiskt)")
Else
    context.Response.Write("inget hände - task: " & task)
End If
```

The `Alarm` class has the following methods:

```
Public Shared Sub Larma(ByVal personId As Integer)
    Dim thread As New System.Threading.Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf Larma_Thread))
    thread.Start(personId)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub Larma_Thread(ByVal personId As Integer)
    StartaLarm(personId)
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 30)
    StoppaLarm(personId)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub StartaLarm(ByVal personId As Integer)
    SandSMS(True, personId)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub StoppaLarm(ByVal personId As Integer)
    SandSMS(False, personId)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub SandSMS(ByVal setOn As Boolean, ByVal personId As Integer)
    ...
End Sub
```

**UPDATE/CLARIFICATION:** I still get the expected response to the client - no error messages - when calling the threaded version.

I also included a forgotten method in the code above.

**Update 2:**
@Henk, Unfortunately I don't have the ability to debug, because this problem arises only on our sharp server, which doesn't have Visual Studio installed and doesn't allow remote debugging.

However, the `SendSMS` method sends text messages to my phone, and both the text message web service and my phone agrees that the messages are sent when calling "on" or "off", but not when calling "larma".

Since I know that the entire chain Handler->`StartaLarm`->`SandSMS(True/False)` works for "on" and "off", I must assume that the failure occurs somewhere in Handler->`Larma`->`Larma_Thread`, and thus is a threading issue.

**Update 3**: @Vadmyst, after converting your code to VB.NET (which is not my favourite of the two either, but this project requires it...) and modifying it to compile, I arrived at the following (although I'm not 100% certain it still means the same thing...):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(Function(p As Integer) Larma_Thread(p)))
```

No success - I have the same results as above... =(

Comment: That clarification says the Threaded version is working??

Comment: @Henk: No - not working, just not giving any errors. As you see in the code, I start a different thread to carry out the tasks, and then return a string to the client. The string is returned, but the tasks are not carried out. Sorry for not being more clear with that.

Comment: And did you Denug to find out if the 2 SendSMS calls are actually executed?

Comment: Is the handler joining with the thread before it exits?
If you put some logging in StartAlarm & StopAlarm do you see that?
What about if you run it on your dev box with logging in SendSMS?

Comment: @danio: No, the handler doesn't join with the thread before it returns to the client and (I assume) exits. The sole reason for doing this in a separate thread is that I *don't* want to wait for the separate thread before returning. I'll see what I can find with some logging and get back.

Comment: @danio: I've attempted some logging, but with no success. We have no logging system in place, and whatever method I use to write to a file, I get permission problems, so we'll just have to go with the information given by the text messages, that implies that the thread is never started, or not started successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an exception in `SandSMS` called from `StartaLarm` called from `Larma_Thread` in the context of a secondary thread. The "nothing happens" behaviour in a multi-threaded application is a strong indication of exception in a secondary thread. The first thing that comes to mind, that is different in a non-request thread of a web application, is that a non-request thread does not have access to `Request`, `Context`, `Session` and such.

Comment: +1 just what I thought. Logging will help, as will setting any thread-local context needed by SendSMS

Comment: It's silly, but this was it. I had a call to `HttpContext.Current...` at the end of a very long line (long because of a string literal) that screwed it all up. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Logging is your friend here. If you're sending an SMS, you should *certainly* be logging before you try and after you've done it (or failed to do it).

For this particular issue, I suggest you add logging before and after you start the thread (or submit the task to the thread pool) too. Basically, the more logging you put in (temporarily, of course) the more idea you'll have what's going on.

Importantly, make sure you log any exceptions which are thrown. You should look in the IIS logs as well, to see if there are any exceptions logged there.

Answer (score 0):

Does SendSMS rely on any ASP.NET internals stuff?
Try using ThreadPool for starting Larma_Thread.

I'm not a VB guru and will try to write the sample with ThreadPool on C#

```
public static void Larma(int personId)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(
            delegate(object unused)
            {
                try
                {
                    Larma_Thread(personId);
                }
                catch { /*log here */}
            }), personId);
    }
```

Comment: After converting to VB with http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ I get an error on `Function` on line 1 (convert to see what I mean) saying "This type of lambda expression is not supported in VB 9.0". Is this supposed to work in .NET < 4?

Comment: That's anonymous method. They were there introduced in .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is important but you're delegate for the parameterized thread start is not of the correct prototype. It should be as follows:

```
<ComVisibleAttribute(False)>
Public Delegate Sub ParameterizedThreadStart ( obj As Object )
```

You have it defined with an input type of int, not sure what would happen here.

See this article on MSDN for more information:

[ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)