# In .NET, what happens to a thread when it finishes its task? Do I need to manage this?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Do I need to do something with this thread after it has completed the Console.WriteLine (suspend it or something) or will garbage collection kick in and remove this thread?

```
public void testThreading() {

    .. do some stuff

    var t = new Thread(() => { Console.WriteLine("hey!"); })
    t.Start();

}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Short Answer:**

When a thread has finished its process, if nothing else holds a reference to it, the garbage collector will dispose of it automatically.

**Long Answer:**

> After the garbage collector is initialized by the CLR, it allocates a
> segment of memory to store and manage objects. This memory is called
> the managed heap, as opposed to a native heap in the operating system.
> There is a managed heap for each managed process.
>
> All threads in the
> process allocate memory for objects on the same heap. To reserve
> memory, the garbage collector calls the Win32 VirtualAlloc function,
> and reserves one segment of memory at a time for managed applications.
> The garbage collector also reserves segments as needed, and releases
> segments back to the operating system (after clearing them of any
> objects) by calling the Win32 VirtualFree function. The fewer objects
> allocated on the heap, the less work the garbage collector has to do.
> When you allocate objects, do not use rounded-up values that exceed
> your needs, such as allocating an array of 32 bytes when you need only
> 15 bytes. When a garbage collection is triggered, the garbage
> collector reclaims the memory that is occupied by dead objects.
>
> The
> reclaiming process compacts live objects so that they are moved
> together, and the dead space is removed, thereby making the heap
> smaller. This ensures that objects that are allocated together stay
> together on the managed heap, to preserve their locality. The
> intrusiveness (frequency and duration) of garbage collections is the
> result of the volume of allocations and the amount of survived memory
> on the managed heap. The heap can be considered as the accumulation of
> two heaps: the large object heap and the small object heap. The large
> object heap contains very large objects that are 85,000 bytes and
> larger. The objects on the large object heap are usually arrays. It is
> rare for an instance object to be extremely large.

Reference

[Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx#S3):-

> A managed thread's lifetime is independent of the Thread object that
> creates it, a very good thing given that you wouldn't want the GC to
> terminate a thread that was still doing work simply because you lost
> all references to the associated Thread object. **So the GC is
> collecting the Thread object, but not the actual managed thread.**
> ..................
>
> The managed thread does not exit (and the memory for its thread stack
> is not released) until its ThreadProc returns or it is explicitly
> killed. So if a managed thread is not properly terminated, the memory
> allocated to its thread stack will leak.

Comment: I beleive that the key phrasing is at the end of that paragraph: "*The managed thread does not exit (and the memory for its thread stack is not released) until its ThreadProc returns or it is explicitly killed.* ***So if a managed thread is not properly terminated, the memory allocated to its thread stack will leak.***" So as you correctly state, it is *NOT* cleaned-up when it's `Thread` object goes out of scope, but rather when the `ThreadProc` exits.

Comment: @RBarryYoung:- Yes. Updated that in the answer! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046355/645511), "after the thread's code finishes executing, the thread will be stopped and its resources reclaimed."